# Login to azure devops using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to login into Azure DevOps using Azure CLI.
I am executing the command from Azure Pipeline (BASH Task)

`az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/someorg/ --pat "somepat"`

I am getting below error on doing so

`========================== Starting Command Output =========================== /usr/bin/bash /home/vsts/work/_temp/bb06f663-b7fd-4249-960f-39a99b7caeeb.sh ERROR: unrecognized arguments: --pat somepat`

I have also tried setting the pipeline variable `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT` and its value and replacing `--pat` with `--token` but didn't worked out.

Can you please help me with it

Azure devops login using azure cli

Comment: I am having the same problem as you, did you solve this?

Comment: @Ostpanaka : Nope the Solution didnt work out.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#pipe-pat-on-stdin-to-az-devops-login), you should not pass the access token via a separate command switch, but either pipe it to the `az devops login` command:

```
echo  "######" | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/contoso/
```

Or set the mentioned environment variable `AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT`. In this case, the login command will take it from that env variable, no need to pass it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for Responding, I implement the changes However I am getting Below errors for the same 

`WARNING: Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
WARNING: You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
WARNING: Refer https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/'
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Bash AZ`